# fstream for reading and writing

Tags: c++, fstream

In test.txt file i have one word "aa". I want to replace it with "aa1". However, the program below does not change the file. What's wrong?

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream iofile("test.txt",ios_base::in|ios_base::app);
    if (!iofile)
            cerr << "Unable to open file!";

    string word;
    iofile >> word;
    word.push_back('1');
    iofile.seekg(0);
    iofile << word;  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realize that `ios_base::app` is causing you to append to the end of the file no matter where you try to seek for write, right? Maybe you meant to specific `ios_base::out` instead?

Also, for writes, it's `seekp()` not `seekg()`.

Comment: Thanx. Replacing ios_base::app with ios_base::out solved the problem. It works both with seekp() and seekg()

Comment: @GrzegorzWilanowski In that limited example, it's likely only working with `seekg()` because the put pointer was still sitting at 0 anyway, and updating the get pointer won't change that... Try doing the same where the string you're writing is not at offset 0 (or immediately after whatever you wrote last)...